# Windows calibration settings persistance over reboots

Tags: windows-7, display, calibration

I'm running Windows 7 64bit on a laptop (Samsung R560) using a cheap external CRT monitor.

The screen is a littler dark for my liking, despite having the physical monitors settings up to the max for all the brightness-related settings.

Windows 7 has a tool called "Calibrate display color" (search in the start menu). Running this tool, you have a slider that allows you to adjust the "Gamma", which sliding up gives me acceptable brightness levels.

Unfortunately, upon reboot (and certain other activities such as running certain fullscreen games) this is reset to default.

Is there a way to make this persistent? Some registry setting? Batch file to run at startup even (less preferable as I'd like games to run brighter too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I see from this laptop's specifications, the graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GS.

NVIDIA drivers contain a control panel (which should be accessible in the system control panel, from the contextual menu on the desktop, or from a tray icon), in which you can set different parameters, like which 3D effects to use, performance on battery, multiple display, etc.

Between these settings, you can also find something like "Adjust Color settings", in which you can set the brightness, gamma, etc. It's possible that these settings have a priority over the ones from the OS, so try to change there, maybe it will keep them.

[image: nvidia control panel]

It should be as well the base for 3D applications such as games, but keep in mind that each of them can set their own, so most likely you would have to deal with each of them individually.

Answer (score 3):

To stop the display resetting to original settings on startup, thus saving your desired gamma, do the following:-

start > run > msconfig > startup > uncheck igfxpers.exe

I just found this out today, after weeks of calibrating every time I start up my laptop! :)

Comment: This was the solution for me on my Dell Vostro 1015 laptop, which uses Intel's integrated graphics card. Thank you my friend, I've been struggling with this for _months_! If I could I'd give you all the reputation points available here at SU on the spot for this fine answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding an automatic event to re-calibrate at specific events, for example unlock etc.

1. Re-calibrate manually: http://www.laszlopusztai.net/2009/08/23/stop-losing-display-calibration-with-windows-7/
2. Automate windows event task to re-calibrate at desired events: https://brianreiter.org/2011/05/03/reducing-the-need-for-manual-reload-of-color-calibration-when-docking-in-windows-7/

A summary of the steps for automating the event:

- Start the windows [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Navigate to the task "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsColorSystem\Calibration Loader"
- Add a new "On workstation unlock" event to trigger the ClibrationLoader task

Now your preset calibrations will be reloaded after unlocking workstation after sleep etc.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.